# Why does my Redux reducer refactor fail?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

Here is an example of what I'm attempting to do:

```
const setView = state => payload => ({ ...state, view: payload });

const reducers = {
  SET_VIEW: setView
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => reducers[action.type](state)(action.payload);
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: reducers[action.type] is not a function

What exactly am I doing wrong?  `reducers` is an object literal with functions.

Comment: Looks like it could work based on what's shown. What is the value of logging `reducers` where the error is thrown?

Comment: @bazzells Nope, Redux dispatches a dummy action on store creation that OP doesn't handle thus the error. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an obscure issue actually. The reason is because, per [the Redux documentation on `createStore`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html):

> When a store is created, **Redux dispatches a dummy action** to your reducer to populate the store with the initial state. You are not meant to handle the dummy action directly. Just remember that your reducer should return some kind of initial state if the state given to it as the first argument is undefined, and you're all set.

And this dummy action mentioned by the documentation just so happens to [be this line the source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L261):

```
dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.INIT })
```

Here, `ActionTypes.INIT` is essentially the string `@@redux/INIT` followed by a random string of numbers and periods.

Thus, when you create the store with `createStore`, a dummy action is dispatched to your reducer, **and that action type does not exist in your `reducers` object**, thus you get the error that undefined isn't a function. That's why you *always* have a default case in your reducer. For example, with a switch statement, you always return state as a default case:

```
switch(action.type) {
  …
  default:
    return state;
}
```

The default case allows for the catching of actions such as the dummy action dispatched by Redux itself. The same principle applies to your code:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => reducers[action.type] ? reducers[action.type](state)(action.payload) : state;
```

This checks to see if the reducer actually exists in the `reducers` object. If it does, it calls the reducer. If not, just like in the default case, the state is just returned.

Comment: Oh wow, TIL.  Thanks for the explanation!  So, it seems kind of silly to have to have a ternary check, I guess I will stick to the switch statements.  Is there a way to avoid that ternary by perhaps doing this check in `combineReducers`?

Comment: Or should I just handle the default case here?  I thought by using object literals I would avoid having a default case ._.

Comment: @scarywolfman I don't think so. Even Redux's documentation recommends roughly the same code for [reducing reducer boilerplate](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html#generating-reducers), albeit more readable. I think it's fine how it is.

Comment: @scarywolfman The "default case" is handled by the ternary operator. If you wish, expanding it out into a full if/else would make it more readable. But you will always need an effective "default case" to catch unknown actions types, in which you just return the current state.

Comment: Thanks for all that info!

Answer (score 1):

@Li357 is correct as to why you are getting that error.  I would like to propose an alternative solution to the problem:

```
const setView = state => payload => ({ ...state, view: payload });

const reducers = {
  SET_VIEW: setView
};

const noop = state => () => state;

export default (state = initialState, action) => (reducers[action.type] || noop)(state)(action.payload);
```

The trick here is the `(reducers[action.type] || noop)` part, which will use a `noop` handler if there isn't a known handler for the action type.  All it does is return the current state.